# How to fetch the images of the logged in user from instagram in iOS

Tags: ios, instagram

```
-(void) viewDidLoad 
{
    NSString *strMethod=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"media/popular?access_token=%@",appDelObj.instagram.accessToken]; 
            [appDelObj.instagram requestWithMethodName:strMethod params:nil httpMethod:@"GET" delegate:self];

}

-(IGRequest*)requestWithMethodName:(NSString*)methodName
                                params:(NSMutableDictionary*)params
                            httpMethod:(NSString*)httpMethod
                              delegate:(id<IGRequestDelegate>)delegate {
        NSString * fullURL = [kRestserverBaseURL stringByAppendingString:methodName];
        return [self openUrl:fullURL
                      params:params
                  httpMethod:httpMethod
                    delegate:delegate];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the URL I was hitting earlier,the earlier used to give me the results of most popular images, but following URL will now give all the images that the user has uploaded

```
 NSString *strMethod=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"users/self/feed?access_token=%@",appDelObj.instagram.accessToken];
                [appDelObj.instagram requestWithMethodName:strMethod params:nil httpMethod:@"GET" delegate:self];
```